How to override ALT-F4 to send SIGKILL instead of default?
I'd like to override the Alt-F4 keyboard shortcut to send a SIGKILL instead of whatever is sent currently. I have a few programs which capture the current signal and do nothing, with no option to re-configure what the behavior of the program is.
How can I make the Alt-F4 keybind send SIGKILL instead of the signal it sends by default?

This is not the exact answer but this is what I use for nasty programs that won't quit:

Press [Alt]+[F2] to open prompt (alternatively open a Terminal)
Type xkill and press [Enter]
The mouse-pointer should change to a Skull-Symbol or so
Click on the window you want to kill.

